Understanding the purpose of .groups = "drop" in dplyr's summarise function
I'm having trouble grasping the purpose of .group = "drop" in dplyr's summarise function. I'm attempting to execute the following code to display the top 20 stations along with their respective latitude and longitude:
summary <- trips_2023 %>% 
    filter(member_casual == "member") %>%
    group_by(start_station_name, start_lat, start_lng) %>%
    summarise(count = n()) %>%
    arrange(desc(count)) %>%
    mutate(type = "start",
           member = "member") %>% 
    slice(1:20) 

However, the code returns a table with many more rows than the requested 20.
If I add .groups = "drop" in the summarise function, then the code works, but honestly, I haven't understood why.
summary <- trips_2023 %>% 
    filter(member_casual == "member") %>%
    group_by(start_station_name, start_lat, start_lng) %>%
    summarise(count = n(), .groups = "drop") %>%
    arrange(desc(count)) %>%
    mutate(type = "start",
           member = "member") %>% 
    slice(1:20) 

.groups = "drop" supposedly instructs dplyr to remove group information after performing grouping and summarising operations.
However, the definition is not clear to me.
I have also read the official documentation, but it's not very understandable.
Can someone help me understand better with a practical example?
Also I am confused by the fact that if I execute the function
groups(summary)

in the first code block (without .groups = "drop"), the output I get is the following:
[[1]]
start_station_name

[[2]]
start_lat

shouldn't start_lng be also a group?
Thanks

Have you read the documentation? At the ?summarize help page there is a pretty detailed description of the .groups argument. Have you read that and are still confused, or have you not read that yet?

The default behavior of summarise() is to remove the last level of grouping after it is called, so in the top example your data is still grouped by start_station_name and start_lat after it is summarised, so your slice(1:20) call returns 20 rows (or all if less than 20) per the number of start_station_name x start_lat groups.  When you use summarise(.groups = "drop") the data frame is returned ungrouped so your slice call returns only 20 rows.

This is a good example of why the newer .by syntax is often simpler. You could do summarize(n = n(), .by = c(start_station_name, start_lat, start_lng)) to do what the group_by + summarize lines do now, without any need to adjust defaults or add ungroup() afterwards.  In the case where you're looking for counts, even simpler to use count(start_station_name, start_lat, start_lng, sort = TRUE) to replace the three lines group_by + summarize + arrange(desc(count))

Hi @Gregor Thomas, I read the documentation, and did not understand it. In general I dislike the documentation: it is not very user friendly and is hard to grasp.

Hi @lotus why you are saying that the data is grouped only by start_station_name and start_lat? I also grouped it using start_lng (that is also related to the second question I ask in the post).
Also, I did not understand your reply, could you please elaborate more?

When you run df |> group_by(var1, var2, var3) |> summarize(...), the default behavior is to give you the summarization for each var1/var2/var3 combination, but with the last grouping removed. This is helpful in some common use cases, eg when you want to summarize in further steps. But it's not the behavior you expect. Your slice(1:20) implicitly presumes the data it receives is no longer grouped at all. .groups = "drop" or ungroup() |> are ways to remove the grouping. Skipping group_by and instead using .by = <grouping vars> within summarize would be yet simpler, outputing ungrouped.

Take this data frame as an example:
ddff <- expand.grid(
  Group1 = LETTERS[1:3],
  Group2 = letters[4:6],
  Group3 = c("foo", "bar"))
ddff$value <- runif(18)

As stated on @lotus' and @JonSpring's comments (and on the function's documentation), by default, summarise will remove the last grouping variable, so when you do
ddff %>%
group_by(Group1, Group2, Group3) %>%
summarise(mean = mean(value))

You get
`summarise()` has grouped output by 'Group1', 'Group2'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.
# A tibble: 18 × 4
# Groups:   Group1, Group2 [9]
   Group1 Group2 Group3   mean
   <fct>  <fct>  <fct>   <dbl>
 1 A      d      foo    0.593
 2 A      d      bar    0.228
 3 A      e      foo    0.830
 4 A      e      bar    0.381
 5 A      f      foo    0.156

Note the # Groups:   Group1, Group2 [9]on the third line.  The result of the summarise function is still grouped by Group1 and Group2.  Group3 has been dropped as a  grouping variable, because it would be redundant: there is only one row per Group1xGroup2 pair, so in all likelihood, you won't want to keep using it for grouping.
This is why asking for the groups() after summarise will only return the first two.
Since the output is still grouped, if we ask for some specific slices, that function will be applied to each group. If we ask for slice(1):
ddff %>%
group_by(Group1, Group2, Group3) %>%
summarise(mean = mean(value)) %>%
slice(1) %>%
nrow()

we get 9, i.e. the first line of each group.

As the message on the output's first line says, this default behaviour can be overriden by using the .groups argument. They are pretty self-explanatory: keep will keep all groups, drop will drop them all:
ddff %>%
group_by(Group1, Group2, Group3) %>%
summarise(mean = mean(value), .groups = "keep") %>%
group_vars()

[1] "Group1" "Group2" "Group3"

ddff %>%
group_by(Group1, Group2, Group3) %>%
summarise(mean = mean(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
group_vars()

character(0)


Thank you so much @Zé Loff, for your clear explanation. I wish all R documentation was written as well as your comment.
